# Error Trying to get property of non-object and Undefined variable: Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am facing the following error:

> Trying to get property of non-object and  Undefined variable php
>   errors in my code

Controller:

```
function showDoctorInformation(){
    $this->load->model('PatientModel');
    $data['doctorinfo'] = $this->PatientModel->getDoctorInformation();
    $this->parser->parse('patient_msgview', $data);

}
```

Model:

```
function getDoctorId() {
        $this->db->from('person');
        $this->db->select('doctorId');
        $doctorId = $this->db->get()->result();
        return $doctorId;
    }

function getDoctorInformation() {


    $doctorId = $this->getDoctorId();

        $this->db->from('DoctorInfo');
        $this->db->where('doctorId', $doctorId);
        $this->db->select('name', 'surname', 'Bio', 'Address', 'img');
        $doctorinfo = $this->db->get()->result();
        return $doctorinfo;

}
```

View:

```
<?= $doctorinfo->name ?>
```

I have displayed information from the database before with this method and I can't see the error now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[result()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)** return

> This method returns the query result as an array of objects, or an
>   empty array on failure

So you need to fetch single data form your database using `->row()`

```
function getDoctorId() {
$this->db->select('doctorId');
$this->db->from('person');
$this->db->select('doctorId');
$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows == 1) {
     $row=$query->row();// fetch single row
     return $row->doctorId;// get doctor id
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
}
```

And in viwe you have to get your data using foreach loop

For exm

```
foreach ($doctorinfo as $row)
{
        echo $row['title'];
        echo $row['name'];
        echo $row['body'];
}
```

Comment: the function getDoctorId is onlly called in the function getDoctorInformation, i have tried but still the same error.

Comment: Yes after using your updated i get this error:


A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: doctorinfo

Filename: views/patient_msgview.php

Line Number: 100

Backtrace:

File: /home/a15_web01/web/application/views/patient_msgview.php
Line: 100
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/a15_web01/web/application/controllers/PatientController.php
Line: 51
Function: parse

File: /home/a15_web01/web/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

Comment: Post your controller code too and value of `print_r($doctorinfo);`

Comment: thats is my controller:
** function showDoctorInformation(){
        $this->load->model('PatientModel');
        $data['doctorinfo'] = $this->PatientModel->getDoctorInformation();
        $this->parser->parse('patient_msgview', $data);
        
    }** and the value i dont see anything when i use print_r($doctorinfo);

Comment: use `echo $this->db->last_query();` to print last query and check it

Comment: that's what i get SELECT * FROM messages WHERE receiver_id = '11' and date_read is null which is definitely not what i want